# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to change a cell value (colour 'red' or 'green') based on a value of another cell. I run the following:

```
df.loc[0, 'Colour'] = df.loc[0, 'Count'].apply(lambda x: 'Red' if x <= 500 
    else 'Green')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `df.loc[0, 'Count']` you are only returning the item that is actually that location which is a `float`. `apply` is a method of a Pandas or numpy series so you need to have a `Series` class to use that method. So most likely you want to do something like this but without a test data set it's hard to know.

```
df['Colour'] = df['Count'].apply(lambda x: 'Red' if x <=500 else 'Green')
```

Creating a test dataset shows you how this works all together:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Colour'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: 'Red' if x <=500 else 'Green')
df.head()
```

Which returns:

```
    A   B   C   D   Colour
0   223 360 133 285 Red
1   300 125 642 238 Red
2   118 293 442 382 Red
3   448 357 55  124 Red
4   995 395 658 559 Green
```

If you want to use `.loc` to access the whole column you can use `df.loc[:, 'Count']` You can read more about the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method here

Comment: Thank you, I do want to change one cell, not a column

Comment: then you can't use apply if you just want to change one cell then you can always use an inline if statement `df.loc[0, 'Colour'] = 'Red' if df.loc[0, 'Count''] <=500 else 'Green'`